# Angular: How to use a custom EventPlugin only inside specific component instead of whole ngModule?

Tags: angular

I have this angular event plugin: (copied from [there](https://github.com/kryops/ng2-events))

```
@Injectable()
    export class UndetectedEventPlugin {
    manager: EventManager;

    supports(eventName: string): boolean {
        return eventName.indexOf('undetected.') === 0;
    }

    addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
        const realEventName = eventName.slice(11);
        return this.manager.getZone().runOutsideAngular(() => this.manager.addEventListener(element, realEventName, handler));
    }
}
```

**If I add it to module provider, it works perfectly everywhere in the app:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,... ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [{
      provide: EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS,
      useClass: UndetectedEventPlugin,
      multi: true
  }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**But, instead, if I add it to a specific component provider like this:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  providers: [{
    provide: EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS,
    useClass: UndetectedEventPlugin,
    multi: true
  }],
  template: `<button (click)="test()">BTN 1: (click)="test()"</button><br><br>
             <button (undetected.click)="test()">BTN 1: (undetected.click)="test()"</button>`,
})
export class HelloComponent {
  test() {
    console.log('TEST FUNCTION')
  }
}
```

It doesn't works.
It seems to have to be global to whole application but I'm not sure about it..

Do you know a way to limit eventPlugin scope to a component?

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk4gpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventManager` is part of the Browser modules, and it receives all of the plugins as part of it's constructor dependencies.

```
/**
 * Initializes an instance of the event-manager service.
 */
constructor(plugins: EventManagerPlugin[], _zone: NgZone);
```

Once an instance of EventManager has been created, then no additional plugins can be added.

You should not use the providers dependencies to perform business logic. If you want to conditionally use the plugin, then add logic to the plugin. You can inject the plugin into your component to configure how it should work based upon the life-cycle of the component.

Comment: That's interesting, so it's not possible. In my case I tried to do that because that's for a library and I don't want whole library users application impacted.. Do you have a code idea for this usecase?

Comment: You can add your own "prefix" to the events so that they are only used by your library, and then implement a "forRoot()" on your module so that you make sure it's loaded in the main module. If you want to listen for click events without change detection, then just add a DOM event listener via vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Yes prefix seems good. About vanilla listeners, it is a bit tricky because elements are inside ngFor loop.. anyway thanks ;)